# Select into a shared server in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a on premise SQL Server and added an Azure SQL Server as a shared server.

Then I have a select statement but I want to select it into a table located on the Azure server.

If I want to specify the full name I get the error

> The object name '[server].[database].dbo.[table]' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

And without it it will create a new table in the on premise database which is not what I want.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server) not supported "Cross-database and cross-instance queries using three or four part names. Three part names referencing the tempdb database and the current database are supported. Elastic query supports read-only references to tables in other MSSQL databases."

Comment: Afaik you would need an Azure managed instance, not a standalone database to be able to implement this; an Azure database is by design self-contained with numerous restrictions.

Comment: you can use linked servers to query azure SQL DB from a SQL Server.  start with sp_addlinkedserver